# Genymotion 2.7.2 cant start after upgrade

Tags: android, linux, intellij-idea, centos, genymotion

I am using genymotion with intellij ultimate. Everything was working fine with version 2.6 and android vm was running well. After that I upgraded genymotion to version 2.7.2 and nothing worked since.

What is happening that I am trying to run the small window of genymotion and start the vm of android in the list. But whatever I press it is stuck and nothing shows on the screen.

Please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

Just download VirtualBox 5.1 and install it, it worked for me

https://www.virtualbox.org/